# Velocity Template Not working

Tags: java, json, velocity

I am trying to parse a json using velocity template. Here is my json string,

```
{\n  \"firstName\": \"Tom\",\n  \"lastName\": \"Geller\",\n  \"department\": \"Retail\",\n  \"manager\": \"Steve\",\n  \"joiningDate\": \"03/08/2011\",\n  \"employees\": [\n    {\n      \"firstName\": \"Paul\",\n      \"lastName\": \"Balmer\",\n      \"department\": \"Retail\",\n      \"manager\": \"Tom Geller\",\n      \"joiningDate\": \"06/21/2014\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"firstName\": \"Eric\",\n      \"lastName\": \"S\",\n      \"department\": \"Retail\",\n      \"manager\": \"Tom Geller\",\n      \"joiningDate\": \"09/13/2014\"\n    }\n  ]\n}
```

This is my velocity template,

```
$firstName $lastName belongs to $department Department. 
His manager is $manager and joining date is $joiningDate.

Employees reporting to him are, 
#foreach( $employee in $employees )
    $employee.firstName $employee.lastName
#end
```

This is the output that gets printed. It doesn't print the reporting employees,

```
Tom Geller belongs to Retail Department. 
His manager is Steve and joining date is 03/08/2011.

Employees reporting to him are,
```

Here is the java code,

```
public class VelocityTemplateDemo {

protected VelocityEngine velocity;

public VelocityTemplateDemo() {
    velocity = new VelocityEngine();
    velocity.init();
}

public String publish(String templatePath, String jsonString) throws IOException {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
    for (Object key : jsonObj.keySet()) {
        String keyString = String.valueOf(key);
        context.put(keyString, jsonObj.get(keyString));
    }
    Writer writer = new StringWriter();
    velocity.mergeTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8", context, writer);
    writer.flush();
    return writer.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String str = "{\n  \"firstName\": \"Tom\",\n  \"lastName\": \"Geller\",\n  \"department\": \"Retail\",\n  \"manager\": \"Steve\",\n  \"joiningDate\": \"03/08/2011\",\n  \"employees\": [\n    {\n      \"firstName\": \"Paul\",\n      \"lastName\": \"Balmer\",\n      \"department\": \"Retail\",\n      \"manager\": \"Tom Geller\",\n      \"joiningDate\": \"06/21/2014\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"firstName\": \"Eric\",\n      \"lastName\": \"S\",\n      \"department\": \"Retail\",\n      \"manager\": \"Tom Geller\",\n      \"joiningDate\": \"09/13/2014\"\n    }\n  ]\n}";
    String result = new VelocityTemplateDemo().publish("/src/main/resources/template.vm", str);
    System.out.println(result);
}

}
```

Comment: Your JSON string isn't JSON. It is a just an escaped string value.

Comment: Added the java code.

Comment: Are you positive that `employees` is being parsed as a JSONArray, or an iterable object when you do `jsonObj.get(keyString)`?

Comment: Once I am done putting the values in the context, my context has all the values from json saved as a HashMap,     {firstName=Tom, lastName=Geller, manager=Steve, joiningDate=03/08/2011, department=Retail, employees=[{"firstName":"Paul","lastName":"Balmer","manager":"Tom Geller","joiningDate":"06/21/2014","department":"Retail"},{"firstName":"Eric","lastName":"S","manager":"Tom Geller","joiningDate":"09/13/2014","department":"Retail"}]}

Comment: It looks like the employees array has more HashMaps or something in it. Suggestion: Use a JSON parser like Jackson or Gson to convert your JSON into Java objects that Velocity can understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `$employees` is a JSONArray, I see two probable causes:

- You are using a version of Apache Velocity anterior to 1.7 (support for the Iterable interface was added in Velocity 1.7)
- You are using a version of json.org anterior to 20150729 (it's the version in which the Iterable interface was added to the JSONArray class)

Comment: Thanks! Velocity version was outdated. Upgraded to 2.0 and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json data to Map/List form using [json](https://github.com/antonsjava/json) library